# Proper way to say "I don't know what the problem is."

Tags: mandarin, simplified-characters

What is the proper way to say "I don't know what the problem is" in Mandarin?
Not sure if this is a “问题” or a "关系“ structure.

Comment: Google Translate : "我不知道是什麼問題".  Which means " I don't know what  problem it is" . You can rephrase it and write "我不知道問題是什麼" which means "I don't know what is the problem " which is closer to the original English sentence in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrase as 'Dunno where the problem lies, (but it won't start.)'

我（也）不知道问题出在哪里,（但是它启动不了。）